# Telerik RadListBox dont want to drag

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

In my asp.net solution i am trying to use Listbox drag and drop capabilyties (like in this example : http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/listbox/examples/functionality/draganddrop/defaultcs.aspx). But the problem ive got now is that drag and drop doesnt work. instead of draging its marking items... i tryed to copy html directly to my page and it still doesnt work. any ideas what can be wrong?

Is it because i miss CSS?

View:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" TagPrefix="telerik" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <!-- ## HEAD SECTION ## -->
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentToolbar" runat="server">
<!-- ## SCRIPT MANAGER ## -->
<asp:ScriptManagerProxy ID="ScriptManagerProxy1" runat="server">
 <Scripts>
    <asp:ScriptReference Path= "~/Scripts/jquery-1.2.6.pack.js" />


 </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManagerProxy>
<%if(false) {%>
  <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.2.6-vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<%} %>

<!-- ## AJAX MANAGER ## -->
<!-- ## AJAX MANAGER ## -->
<telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" OnAjaxRequest="RadAjaxManager1_AjaxRequest" runat="server">
</telerik:RadAjaxManager>
    <!-- ## TOOLBAR ## -->
    <telerik:RadToolBar ID="RadToolBar1" runat="server"
                        OnButtonClick="Toolbar_ButtonClick"
                        EnableEmbeddedSkins="False"
                        OnClientButtonClicked="OnClientButtonClicked"
                        CssClass="pickers_width"
                        Skin="AgendaSkin">
        <Items>
            <telerik:RadToolBarButton   AccessKey="<%$ Resources:Shortcuts, GLOBAL_SAVE %>"
                                        PostBack="false"
                                        Text="<%$ Resources:Language, Generel.Expression.SaveAndClose %>"
                                        CommandName="SAVEANDCLOSE"
                                        Value="SAVEANDCLOSE"
                                        ImageUrl="~/Images/Icons/save_16.png"></telerik:RadToolBarButton>

            <telerik:RadToolBarButton   AccessKey="<%$ Resources:Shortcuts, POPUPS_RETURN %>"
                                        PostBack="False"
                                        Text="<%$ Resources:Language, Generel.Expression.Close %>"
                                        CommandName="CLOSE"
                                        ImageUrl="~/Images/Icons/close_16.png"></telerik:RadToolBarButton>
        </Items>
    </telerik:RadToolBar>

</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentHeader" runat="server">

    <!-- ## HEADER (TITLE BAR) ## -->


</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentWorkspace" runat="server">
  <div class="pickers_workspace_row_margin">
    <!-- ## WORKSPACE ## -->
    <div class="prof_item">
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlRoleList" runat="server" CssClass="prof_item_value_section">

       <telerik:RadAjaxPanel ID="RadAjaxPanel1" runat="server" CssClass="example-panel">
        <telerik:RadListBox ID="RadListBox1" runat="server" Width="200px" Height="200px" 
            SelectionMode="Single" AllowReorder="true"
            EnableDragAndDrop="true" OnDropped="RadListBox1_Dropped">

        </telerik:RadListBox>
    </telerik:RadAjaxPanel>
        </asp:Panel>
    </div>
  </div>
 <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hidRoleInObjectUId" />
 <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hidRoleInObjectName" />
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content5" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentScripts" runat="server">

    <!-- ## SCRIPT SECTION ## -->
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

        function CloseWindow() {
            // Return userdata to calling window
            if (window.opener != null) {
                window.opener.ClearBlocker();
                window.ReturnFunction();
                window.close();
            }
        }



        function SaveEditedFields(commandName) {
            var ajaxManager = $find("<%= RadAjaxManager1.ClientID %>");
            ajaxManager.ajaxRequest(commandName);
        }

        function OnClientButtonClicked(sender, args) {
            var button = args.get_item();
            var commandName = args.get_item().get_commandName()

            switch (commandName) {
                case "SAVEANDCLOSE":
                    SaveEditedFields(commandName);
                    break;

                case "SAVE":
                    SaveEditedFields(commandName);
                    break;

                case "CLOSE":
                    CloseWindow();
                    break;
            }
        }    

    </script>

</asp:Content>
```

**CS :**

```
    private void FillMandatoryItemFirstList(Guid item_guid)
    {
        //MandatoryItems First



        IEnumerable<MandatoryItem> mandatoryFirst = MandatoryItem.GetMandatoryItemByCommitteeAndPos(item_guid, Enums.GetGuidFromEnum(Enums.AgendaElementPositionEnum.PosFirst));
        foreach (var item in CheckCount(mandatoryFirst))
        {
                    RadListBox1.Items.Add(new RadListBoxItem(item.UIdHandlingItemHandlingItem.Title, item.Id.ToString()));

        }

    }
```

Comment: can you post your html and code? otherwise it's hard to guess what's wrong.

Comment: what is the error you are getting, you must be getting atleast a javascript error. If you are not getting any error, can you send aspx , cs code (js also if you have)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried replacing your standard ScriptManager with a RadScriptManager?

Comment: Solved: problem was in client settings